# Can't save product attribute adjustment

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

If i adjust a product attribute, i get an error:

Method "checkReservedAttributeCodes" is not defined in "Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer"

Using magento 1.9.2.4.

Comment: Did you make any changes to your Magento core files?

Comment: No have not make any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Please add below function in your file **app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Observer.php**

```
public function checkReservedAttributeCodes(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var $attribute Mage_Catalog_Model_Entity_Attribute */
    $attribute = $observer->getEvent()->getAttribute();
    if (!is_object($attribute)) {
        return;
    }
    /** @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    if ($product->isReservedAttribute($attribute)) {
        throw new Mage_Core_Exception(
            Mage::helper('catalog')->__('The attribute code \'%s\' is reserved by system. Please try another attribute code', $attribute->getAttributeCode())
        );
    }
}
```